# How to check what sms was sent by me in conversation?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I made query to `content://sms/` to get all sms entries. I can group them by thread_id for displaying as conversation. But how can i check what sms was sent by me? cause i cant get any useful info from address or person columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each message has a type column. Check this against MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT and MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX defined in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html